# unable to run unix command in python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

trying the following lines of code.

```
status= subprocess.Popen('ls -lrt',shell= True)
status.communicate()
rtrn_cd= status.returncode
print('rtrn_cd is {}'.format(rtrn_cd))
```

everytime I am getting rtrn_cd as 1 instead of 0

Comment: What's written to stderr by the `ls` command? It should explain _why_ it returns a nonzero exit status.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't happen everywhere -- see an exit status 0 reported at https://ideone.com/cqzN7p. We need a [mre] that lets us see a problem ourselves before we can solve it.